# python: retrieve names of all builtins

Tags: python, built-in

How can I retrieve names of all `builtins` for my current `python` distribution during runtime?

Comment: Which builtins are you referring to? The methods and properties of an object, the modules in the standard library? The standard functions?

Comment: I mean those: http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/functions.html, but now I realized, that I also need builtin types and exceptions too.

Comment: Since it's in the documentation, what more do you need to know?

Comment: I don't want to retype in my program, but have the names retrieved.

Comment: "I don't want to retype in my program"?

Comment: My program analyzes python code and it must know names of built in objects. I can type those names by hand from documentation, but that really sucks - that's not what we created computers for ;-) So I wanted to retrieve those names somehow for the current version of python implementation.

Comment: Please update your question to be complete.  Please don't add important information in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this suffices, but you can fire up the interpreter and do the following

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'apply', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 'unicode', 'vars', 'xrange', 'zip']
```

And you can see the dir value

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'atexit']
```

And from the modules, you can import builtin as module

- http://effbot.org/librarybook/builtin.htm

Comment: However, if I call it inside a module, I don't get what I want. Why it is different? I actually I need to call it inside a module, but ther e I don't get all those names, but rather ['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', , '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__','__sizeof__','__str__', '__subclasshook__','clear','copy','fromkeys','get', 'items','keys','pop','popitem','setdefault','update','values']

Comment: Ok, it seems, I can `import builtins` in python 3k and simply run `dir` on it. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @gruszczy : Correct, The dir provides the namespace and in your case it is providing the namespace from where you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> dir(builtins)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BaseExceptionGroup', 'BlockingIOError', 'BrokenPipeError', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'ChildProcessError', 'ConnectionAbortedError', 'ConnectionError', 'ConnectionRefusedError', 'ConnectionResetError', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EncodingWarning', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'ExceptionGroup', 'False', 'FileExistsError', 'FileNotFoundError', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'InterruptedError', 'IsADirectoryError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'ModuleNotFoundError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotADirectoryError', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'PermissionError', 'ProcessLookupError', 'RecursionError', 'ReferenceError', 'ResourceWarning', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StopAsyncIteration', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'TimeoutError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__build_class__', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'abs', 'aiter', 'all', 'anext', 'any', 'ascii', 'bin', 'bool', 'breakpoint', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'exec', 'exit', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'vars', 'zip']
```

Just the built-in functions (no exceptions or [dunder variables](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/dunder-variables/)):

```
>>> print(*[name for name in dir(builtins) if name[0].islower()], sep="\n")
abs
aiter
all
anext
any
ascii
bin
bool
breakpoint
bytearray
bytes
callable
chr
classmethod
compile
complex
copyright
credits
delattr
dict
dir
divmod
enumerate
eval
exec
exit
filter
float
format
frozenset
getattr
globals
hasattr
hash
help
hex
id
input
int
isinstance
issubclass
iter
len
license
list
locals
map
max
memoryview
min
next
object
oct
open
ord
pow
print
property
quit
range
repr
reversed
round
set
setattr
slice
sorted
staticmethod
str
sum
super
tuple
type
vars
zip
```